# Are all of Barry’s memories of his old life back in his head? (Spoilers for season 3)

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

***A word of warning...this question reveals plot points from season 3, episode 1.***

In *The Flash* 3x01 "Flashpoint", the alternate timeline Barry’s in

> starts to overwrite the reality Barry knows and he starts losing his memories of his life as The Flash

Transcription from a scene:

> **Thawne**: And here, I was starting to think you'd forgotten all
>  about me. 
>  **Barry:** But I am forgetting. What's happening to me?  
>  **Thawne**: I was wondering when you'd notice. 
>  **Barry**: It's like I'll be thinking of a moment from my past and then it... It vanishes. I can't get it back. Why? 
>  **Thawne**: Flashpoint. It's a side effect. See, I told you before. You don't know what you're doing. This new reality you've created is
>  starting to overwrite the reality that you and I know. So your
>  original life... Your friends, your family... Pretty soon, all of that
>  will just fade away 
>  **Barry**: Why isn't it happening to you? 
>  **Thawne**: Not sure.  Unless... 
>  **Barry**: What? What?  What the hell's so funny? 
>  **Thawne**: Your speed!  The more you use it, the faster you lose your memories.  
>  **Barry**: No. No, you're lying. You just want me to let you out of here. That's never gonna happen. 
>  **Thawne**: The you I know from the future, he's not this stupid. Pretty soon, you won't even remember that you're The Flash. And when
>  that happens, this world will become permanent. Time will set like
>  concrete, and nothing will be able to change it back to the way it
>  was.

But at the end of the episode,

> Barry decides to fix the timeline and then Eobard kills Barry's mom
>  and the timeline is fixed; the events of season 1 and 2 still
>  happened, although some are slightly different, for example Joe and Iris.

So: are all of his memories of

> his old life — i.e. the events of season 1 and 2 — back in his head?

Comment: Thanks again for the second question with all the plot an' stuf...still haven't seen it yet.

Comment: im really sorry i dint know you dint see it

Comment: S'OK Andrew....follow this link and scroll down to the bit about spoilers... 
http://scifi.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: i cant get it to worjk for both can you help me please

Comment: Done - just needs a peer review. Let's go into chat to review the other question.

Comment: As of the 4 way crossover (ep10?) it does seem as if he has a near perfect set of memories about the events from seasons 1-2 since he can identify changes. He does not appear to have many (any?) memories of his current life prior to coming back from Flashpoint since he persists in trying to befriend Cisco (have they even mentioned the circumstances of Dante's death?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Speculation based on Observation: It is unlikely Barry's memories will be the same as they were when he left home. That particular version of him has moved around past the Flashpoint, caused ripples in space-time, twice, possible three times, and these temporal ripples are crashing together causing discontinuities in the timelines.

> Each time he has changed the past would likely have had no serious long-term effects he would notice, but significant changes alter time appreciably making greater ripples and having greater effects on behavior, choices and possible outcomes for those characters.

I believe as he continued to live, the past was rewriting itself to matching his awareness to the timeline he is now living in.

> When he returned to what he believes is his timeline, his memory loss probably stops but since there have been changes in the timeline in the distant past, there are likely ripples and echoes of events which might not match his memories, events which happened because of these changes to this singular event which cast minor fluctuations through time.

Things he did not "know" when he arrived, he will eventually "learn" and his memory will adjust accordingly. Assuming he is home in the first place...

Comment: +1 This also fits with what happened during "Flashpoint" itself -- as he drew on the Speed Force to use his powers, his memories began rewriting themselves to fit the new timeline. _If_ the show is consistent, that will continue to happen.